# Add text in public class C# & unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add text to the class created in my code.
My problem is that it does not recognize the text and is not added.
In the created class, there are 3 sections, which are filled in 3 parts in order, but the main problem is that the text is not added in class c1.set1
This code is executed in Unity.
Also coded with Visual 2017.
I hope I have made the problem clear.

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class c1
{
    public string set1;
    public string set2;
    public string set3;
}


public class stringToArray : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] S1;
    public c1[] c1_item;
    public int x;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        S1 = new string[20];// It works properly
        while (x<10)
        {
            S1[x]= string.Format("ok "+x,x);
            x++;

        }

        c1_item = new c1[20];
        while (x < 10)
        {
            //S1[x] = string.Format("ok " + x, x); // It works properly
            c1_item[x].set1 = string.Format("ok "+x , x); // It does not work properly
x++;

        }

    }

    
}
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: When you get to the while for c1_item, x is *still* set to 10 from the S1 loop.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but even if it is, it is still wrong
`
void Start()
    {
        S1 = new string[10]; // It works properly
        while (x<10)
        {
            S1[x]= string.Format("ok "+x,x);
            x++;

        }
        x = 0;
        c1_item = new c1[10];
        while (x < 10)
        {
            //S1[x] = string.Format("ok " + x, x); // It works properly
            c1_item[x].set1 = string.Format("ok "+x , x); // It does not work properly
            x++;

        }

    }
`
My main goal is for the c1_item[x].set1 = ????? section to work properly

Comment: Please add/edit the code into your OP so we can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so your problem is that you haven't actually created the `c1` objects to store your values, you've only created the `c1_items` array to hold the referencese to the objects.

```
void Start() {

    // 'string' is (treated as) a value type, does not need to be initialised
    S1 = new string[20];// It works properly

    while (x < 10) {
        S1[x] = string.Format("ok " + x, x);
        x++;
    }

    x = 0; // reset x

    // !! CAUSE: 'c1' is a reference type (class), it only holds references and not actual objects
    c1_item = new c1[20];

    while (x < 10) {
        // !! FIX: MUST add the object first
        if (c1_item[x] == null) c1_item[x] = new c1();
        
        c1_item[x].set1 = string.Format("ok " + x, x); // It does not work properly
        x++;
    }
}
```

What can be tricky is that you've set `c1_item` as `public`, which means that Unity will instantiate and manage all the required objects within the array. The issue here is that you wipe that out and generate your own array (`new c1[]`), which means you also have to be the one to add the objects.

(Of note, if your `c1` was a `struct` instead of a `class` this wouldn't have come up)

Answer (score 0):

first of all **using UnityEngine;** might be helpful so don't always delete it
you need also **using System.Collections;** and **using System.Collections.Generic;** for the usage of lists and arrays.
I recommend that you initiate S1 before the start I mean in the awake method.

```
public int x = 0; // doesn't hurt to give it a value
```

you also need the x to be positive yes ? because it will be the index in a list of string so use range and test the x before working with it ,example :

```
[Range(0,20)]
public int x = 0;
```

Or

```
   void Start()
        {
    if(x>=0){
//do code
}
    }
```

Now why your code line doesn't work

```
c1_item[x].set1 = string.Format("ok "+x , x); // It does not work properly
```

I recommend using this

```
if(c1_item.Length >= x){
 c1 newC1 = c1_item[x];
 newC1.set1 = string.Format("ok "+x , x);}
```